# npm run fails because IntelliJ can't find npm even though it is installed

Tags: intellij-idea, npm, windows-10

On my `windows 10`, in my `build.sbt` in `Intellij IDE`, I have a function `def runDevBuild(implicit dir: File): Int = ifUiInstalled(runScript("npm run build"))`. When I run it, I get error `'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. `npm` is installed and I have added it in the `PATH` variable.

```
C:\Users\surface>where npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
```

I have also added paths to `npm` and `node` in `Intellij` settings.

Why is the script not running?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the issue was that I had to restart the IntelliJ IDE. Enterinng `node` and `npm` in `IntelliJ` seem to have worked

Comment: environment is only loaded on the process start, so you have to re-start IDEA after changing your system `%PATH%`

Answer (score -1):

delete the node_modules from your directory.use git bash run this command

```
npm -i -g
```